strings as functions during parsing
TL;DR
Given: sequence of Token and Grammar 
Where: 
   Token := tuple[name:string, value:string, parent:Token] 
   Grammar := Table[system.string, proc(x:Token):string] 
Return: string of token values passed through the grammar

When implementing my translator, I came to the conclusion that I need to perform some action depending on the token, I understand that it would be more correct to implement this functionality using conditional branching, but I am interested in a different approach, in which, having received the name of the token, I do some interaction with it.
The easiest way to implement this is Table[system.string, proc(x:Token):string]
However, I am not satisfied with the fact that I cannot generate it during compilation. Or I can, but I don't know how.
Since I have a little experience with php, from which I know that I can work with strings as functions
    function a(int $num){ 
        return $num + 3;
    }
    echo "a"(1); // 4

Based on this, is there a way in Nim that would allow declaring a set of functions in advance to access them in this way?

Or maybe you can suggest how to take more correct approaches to this problem.

Maybe this is what you want (but this is a quick implementation)
import tables
import macros, macrocache

const procs = CacheTable"procs"

macro addToProcs(def: untyped): untyped =
  procs[def.name.strVal] = def.name
  result = def

macro genTable(t: untyped): untyped =
  result = newNimNode(nnkTableConstr)
  for name, ident in procs.pairs:
    let expr = newNimNode(nnkExprColonExpr)
    expr.add newLit(name)
    expr.add quote do:
      `t`(`ident`)
    # https://internet-of-tomohiro.pages.dev/nim/faq.en#procedures-how-to-get-a-pointer-to-a-overloaded-procedureqmark
    # use a type conversion to avoid ambiguous name `add`
    result.add expr

proc add(a: int, b: int): int {.addToProcs.} =
  a + b

proc sub(a: int, b: int): int {.addToProcs.} =
  a - b

const table = toTable genTable(typeof(sub)) # here I don't use `add` because the name `add` has many overloads in the stdlib

echo table["add"](1, 2)

This is my first attempt, even harsher.
import tables
import macros

macro genTable(names: static seq[string]): untyped =
  result = newNimNode(nnkTableConstr)
  for name in names:
    let expr = newNimNode(nnkExprColonExpr)
    expr.add newLit(name)
    expr.add ident(name)
    result.add expr

proc add_uniq(a: int, b: int): int =
  a + b

proc sub_uniq(a: int, b: int): int =
  a - b


let table = toTable genTable(@["add_uniq", "sub_uniq"])

echo table["add_uniq"](1, 2) # 3

Also, you can define a call operator for strings:
template `()`(s: string, a: int, b: int): int =
  table[s](a, b)

